# Trouble with \begin{appendices} and part contents in Spanish

Tags: babel, appendices, appendix, spanish

In the Spanish version of my free physics text I have a problem with the command \begin{appendices}. It writes the line

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}Unidades, medidas y constantes}{381}{Apéndice.a.A}
```

into the file .ptc which is created by the `\startcontents[part3]` and `\stopcontents[part3]` commands.

When the command `\printcontents` reads this line, an error occurs, because of the accent in the last bracket. The dvi and ps files are produced. 
But the error is so bad that Adobe Distiller bombs when converting the ps to pdf.

Note: I use \usepackage{appendix} and \startcontents[part3] \stopcontents[part3]

How can I avoid that accent? Where does it come from? I cannot find the origin. It comes from a call to \l@chapter which takes two arguments. But all this is so deep inside latex, I do not know what to do.

Thank you for any help. The Spanish version is free and almost ready, but this issue makes is difficult...

Please do not answer asking for a minimal working example. It is not possible, sorry - I use a 4000 line long .cls file plus about 60 packages.

**Start of the .cls file, with the first 16 packages:**

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside,onecolumn,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{etex}                %  
\usepackage{index}               % several indices 
\usepackage{appendix}            % allows to mix chapters and appendices
\usepackage[OT2, T1]{fontenc}    % OT2 is for cyrillic  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      %  
\usepackage{colortbl}            % 
\usepackage{booktabs}            % For good tables  
\usepackage{longtable,ltcaption} % 
\usepackage{colordvi}            % Defines \Color for titles
\usepackage[dvips,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} % take out option cmyk  
\usepackage{pst-plot}            %  
\usepackage{pstricks-add}        %  
\usepackage{psfrag}              % 
\usepackage{graphicx}            %
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps} %{,.jpg,.pdf} Since I use the dvi-ps-pdf
\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}    % For small figures
\usepackage[originalparameters]{ragged2e}    % For captions of small figures
```

**Start of appendix:**

```
\begin{appendices} 
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\chapter{Unidades, medidas y constantes}
```

**More details:**

`\startcontents` is inserted by hand in the preface; it is a command from the `titletoc` package.

Nowhere is "Appendix" redefined in the code.
This appears to be done somewhere unwanted, but hidden in one of the 60 packages.

Comment: You give very little information. Where does `\startcontents` come from? What compiler are you using --- tex, latex, pdflatex, context, ...? Something in your code, not shown, redefines the appendix name to the accented version. I'm sure that you could provide an MWE; It only has to show the class you are using, the relevant packages, `\tableofcontents` and the start of your appendices.

Comment: I added all data I could get.

Comment: You ask us not to ask you for a minimal example, but you don't give us anything that would allow us to reproduce (or even understand) your problem. You can provide a link to the class file, but you still need to provide a minimal example that shows the problem. Most of the 60 package are not going to be relevant, so remove them. Having people guess what your code is like is not a productive way to get help.

Comment: The component of the line with the accent looks like a bookmark, so it is associated with `hyperref`.  It is also specific to the language.  This eliminates (probably) most packages.  Make a guess at the packages that could be related, and look into their innards to find the culprit.  (The place where they are read from will be shown in the log.)  Then (this is just a guess) redefine the likely culprit, as late in the preamble as possible, or possibly after `\begin{document}`, to use `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: Which package provides the `\selectlanguage{spanish}` macro? That might be where your problem lies.

Comment: That command  comes from babel; the package is so well maintained that it should have no issues. But I am still checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with TexLive 2020. So I cannot say what the origin was (the problem arose with TexLive 2017), but updating is worth the trouble.